# How can I get a list of PHP errors occurred in a page?

Tags: php, zend-framework

When I go to one of my php pages, I receive a bunch of errors. Some are a few warnings and one of which is a fatal error.

I was trying to find out if my page has any fatal errors. Is there a way to get a list of errors occurred on that page, so I can determine if a fatal error exists?

The function error_get_last() doesn't solve my purpose because it lists only the last occurred error and that might not necessarily be a fatal error.

Thanks,

Comment: Not if its a parse error, since the PHP script will never be executed.

Comment: okay..what about other errors?

Comment: This may sound dumb, but what errors can occur after a fatal error? Isn't a fatal error always the last on the page? By analogy, humans don't make many more errors after a fatal one. :P

Comment: Warnings (E_COMPILE_ERROR) preceeds fatal errors

Comment: The idea here is if you have a warning preceeding fatal error, error_get_last() gets the warning instead of fatal error. I am trying to find a solution to some how figure out if a fatal error occurred.

Comment: `filectime` and `filemtime` can record warnings that are received by `error_get_last()`, but do not interrupt execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see what could be the use case for this, but to answer your question- you could set your own error handler, and catch all errors:

```
$errors = array();

set_error_handler(function($code, $msg, $file, $line, $context) use(&$errors){
  $errors[] = compact('code', 'msg', 'file', 'line', 'context');
});
```

And check that array at the end of the script.

To "catch" fatal errors check for `error_get_last()` during shutdown:

```
register_shutdown_function(function(){
  $error = error_get_last();

  if($error && in_array($error['type'], array(E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_COMPILE_ERROR)){
    // some kind of fatal error        
  }
});
```

Comment: The use case is to try to catch fatal errors and not display them to the user, but to handle them and show user friendly message. If the page has only one error which happens to be a fatal error, I can get it through error_get_last(), but if the page has multiple errors including a fatal error, the last error might not be the fatal error.

Comment: I think you should throw exceptions, catch them and display your friendly message. Your script should not generate E_type errors in the first place

Comment: Various built-in functions can generate errors that you may want to access.